# Can't get my CSS Stylesheet in my HTML Sheet

Tags: html, css

I have my HTML file and my CSS file in the same folder, but I can still not find it using the following code:

`<link rel="Stylesheet" href="style.css">`

If I continue coding, it is stating that "Some content has been disabled in this document" as my program is stating. If I remove the code, it continues to work just normally. I do not know why this is happening, as I have made HTML and CSS programs before, and I was using the same technic.

Comment: What if you add ./ before the style.css or put the exact path of your css file

Comment: Maybe try adding the attribute: `type="text/css"`
Also, maybe change `rel="Stylesheet"` to `rel="stylesheet"` (all lowercase)

Comment: Can you please share your directory structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found a solution. I normally can find my sheets easily using only the name of the file. But It did not work this time, so I did what fmsthird said, trying to put the exact path of my file instead. I totally forgot this feature, and it fixed it. I still do not know why I could not have done the other thing, and I spent 30 minutes trying to fix this.

The solution was so easy, and I totally forgot about it haha.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
    <title>Website Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

you need to add the line into the head as displayed. Also it needs to add: `type="text/css"`